# How do we get more traffic to the site?

Tags: discussion

We have only had activity on 3 questions in the past 2 days.  It is recommended that we get 10 new questions per day.  This is far below these goals.

What can we do to get more questions?

Comment: OK so it has been a year since this was asked.  We are still averaging 1.5 questions per day.  It is time to get moving.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry too much about it.

We're still currently in the private beta stage, and we'll be in this spot for another 9 days. After nearly two weeks of private beta, it's perfectly natural for activity to slow down.

### So what should you do?

Don't lose out. Make sure that you keep your commitment to this strong. Keep active on meta, working through the queues and discussing site issues.

Quantity is not everything. Whatever you do, never sacrifice quality in these critical stages. Don't ask questions simply for the sake of asking: if you do, you're bailing out on the site. Continue answering questions with quality. If you start seeding the site with lower-quality questions, you'll destroy the site. I've seen this happen. You've got a reputation so far, make sure to keep it, or even improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Sending out additional private-beta invites could help, too (without, of course, going overboard).

Comment: How could we go overboard with this.  We should keep an eye to make sure we can keep up with the answers we receive; but, I think we can handle WAY MORE than 1.5 question/day.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Erik.  This is something we need to improve on if we want the site to be viable and [Graduate from Beta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/).  Our Beta stats on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438?phase=beta) need improvement.

We are doing great on answering questions (94%) - GREAT JOB!!!
We have the quality answers and users, now we need quantity to meet our Beta Goals.

**6,000 members is REALLY LOW.**

Forbes that ["More than 278,000 desktop 3D printers (under $5,000) were sold worldwide..."](https://www.forbes.com/sites/tjmccue/2016/04/25/wohlers-report-2016-3d-printer-industry-surpassed-5-1-billion/#1886464619a0)  in 2016.  I am SURE that the majority of the owners are looking for answers.  In the past year since beta started, the 3D printing market has exploded (nearly 300K users); but, we have only added 50% do our user base (2K users).  WHY?

**1.5 questions a day is (IMHO) DISMAL**.

I am a member of a Facebook Group for just the Tronxy X1/X3.
It has 1,500 members (1/4 of what we have) and gets at least 10 questions/day.

**So, what can we do?**

Here is the [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252762/what-can-be-done-to-promote-beta-sites) on Stack Exchange Meta and here are some SO Blog Posts on [Community Promotion Ads](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/) and [A Recipe to Promote your Site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/23/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

**So, Who is With Me?**
**Who wants this site THE SOURCE for 3D Printing questions and answers?**

Comment: I wonder if we can use [community-ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-ads/info)